# How can I copy one column (field) from one table to an empty column (field) of another table both of which are part of same database using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, copy, field

I'm using MySQL with Sequel Pro on a Mac OS X.  I would like to copy one field (i.e., a column called "GAME_DY") from one table into an empty field of another table called "DAY_ID".  Both tables are part of the same database.  I've searched the answers to similar/same questions, but cannot find an answer with manipulable code that works.

Database: retrosheet

Table 1 (Existing table called "game") from which I would like to copy field "GAME_DY"

```
Fields:
GAME_ID,
YEAR_ID,
GAME_DT,
GAME_CT,
GAME_DY,
START_GAME_TM,
....
```

Table 2 (existing Table called "starting_pitcher_game_log") to which I would like to copy to field "DAY_ID":

```
Fields: 
PIT_ID,
GAME_ID,
W,
L,
IP,
BFP,
H,
R,
DAY_ID,
DATE
....
```

I want to copy "GAME_DY from TABLE 1 into "DAY_ID" in TABLE 2.

Can this be done using MySQL queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update existing records in the `starting_pitcher_game_log` field, you could use SQL like this:

```
UPDATE starting_pitcher_game_log SET DAY_ID = (
  SELECT GAME_DY FROM game, starting_pitcher_game_log
  WHERE game.GAME_ID = starting_pitcher_game_log.GAME_ID
)
```

Comment: Thank you bunnmatt!  With the exact code you use, you get an error: You can't specify target target table 'starting_pitcher_game_log' for update in FROM clause.  But when you remove the "starting_pitcher_game_log" from the FROM statement, then it works like a charm.  Thank you.  UPDATE starting_pitcher_game_log 
SET DAY_ID = (
  SELECT GAME_DY 
  FROM game
  WHERE game.GAME_ID = starting_pitcher_game_log.GAME_ID)